# What is the correct way to get a subarray in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am trying to get a subarray in scala, and I am a little confused on what the proper way of doing it is.  What I would like the most would be something like how you can do it in python:

```
x = [3, 2, 1]
x[0:2]
```

but I am fairly certain you cannot do this.

The most obvious way to do it would be to use the Java Arrays util library.

```
import java.util.Arrays
val start = Array(1, 2, 3)
Arrays.copyOfRange(start, 0, 2)
```

But it always makes me feel a little dirty to use Java libraries in Scala.  The most "scalaic" way I found to do it would be

```
def main(args: List[String]) {
    val start = Array(1, 2, 3)
    arrayCopy(start, 0, 2)
}
def arrayCopy[A](arr: Array[A], start: Int, end: Int)(implicit manifest: Manifest[A]): Array[A] = {
    val ret = new Array(end - start)
    Array.copy(arr, start, ret, 0, end - start)
    ret
}
```

but is there a better way?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You can call the slice method:

```
scala> Array("foo", "hoo", "goo", "ioo", "joo").slice(1, 4)
res6: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(hoo, goo, ioo)
```

It works like in python.

Comment: Yes you're right. I was referring to the bound conventions. The lower bound is included and the upper is excluded. There is no trailing `:` neither.

Comment: @nnythm The link is head.

Comment: Looks like I can't edit a comment that stale, but an alive link is: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps.html

Comment: @nnythm You can however _delete_ the older comment ;)

Answer (score 20):

Imagine you have an array with elements from `a` to `f`

```
scala> val array = ('a' to 'f').toArray // Array('a','b','c','d','e','f')
```

Then you can extract a sub-array from it in different ways:

1. Dropping the first n first elements with `drop(n: Int)`

   `array.drop(2) // Array('c','d','e','f')`
2. Take the first n elements with `take(n: Int)`

   `array.take(4) // Array('a','b','c','d')`
3. Select any interval of elements with `slice(from: Int, until: Int)`. Note that `until` is excluded.

   `array.slice(2,4) // Array('c','d')`

   The slice method is stricly equivalent to:
   `array.take(4).drop(2) // Array('c','d')`
4. Exclude the last n elements with `dropRight(n: Int)`:

   `array.dropRight(4) // Array('a','b')`
5. Select the last n elements with `takeRight(n: Int)`:

   `array.takeRight(4) // Array('c','d','e','f')`

**Reference**: [Official documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html)

Answer (score 1):

An example of extracting specific columns from a 2D Scala Array (original_array):

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

val sub_array = ArrayBuffer[Array[String]]()
val columns_subset: Seq[String] = Seq("ColumnA", "ColumnB", "ColumnC")
val columns_original = original_array(0)

for (column_now <- columns_subset) {
      sub_array += original_array.map{_(columns_original.indexOf(column_now))}
    }
sub_array
```