# Scala: sub-array

Tags: arrays, scala

Is there any built-in function in Scala that takes a part of an array and creates a new array from this part?
Something that makes the following pseudo-code:

```
newarr = oldarr[3:5]
```

meaning, newarr is an array of 3 elements, that:

```
newarr[0]=oldarr[3]
newarr[1]=oldarr[4]
newarr[2]=oldarr[5]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to get a subarray in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830944/what-is-the-correct-way-to-get-a-subarray-in-scala)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
val newarr = oldarr.slice(3,6) // from index 3 until (not including) index 6
```

Study the [Standard Library](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Array).  It's amazing what you'll find there.